# python opencv pixel by pixel compare image with template

Tags: python, image, opencv, compare

I need a function which compares pixel by pixel two images of the same size. The result is supposed to be a some alert if image == template. Using python and opencv.

Comment: Please show us what you already have, give some code.

Comment: alredy i have no code , because i don't know any function to compare images pixel by pixel. if you know some please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can directly compare two arrays of the same size for truth -

```
array1==array2
```

The output will be a Boolean array showing if values are equal at each of the coordinates